# Volume of a curved cone

Tags: volume

Apparently, the volume of this cone is $\frac{1}{16}\pi r^2h$. My question is why this is the case, can someone please geometrically explain the reason behind the $\frac{1}{16}$ bit. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: @PichiWuana im not sure if this is relevant to obtain the 1/16 part but the radius is supposed to be proportional to the square of its height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given variation of radius is second degree.

$$ (z/h)^2 = (y/r) $$

$$ V = \pi \int_0^h y^2 dz $$

Evaluating  it

$$ V = \frac{\pi r^2 h} {5} $$

The given degree of " cone" parabola is too low.

If it is given as

$$ (z/h)^{15/2} = (y/r) $$

only then given result is ok.